# asynchronous global variable behavior with intra module globals in python

Tags: python, global-variables

So I have a global variables module global_var.py that looks like this:

```
x = 1
y = 2
```

When I want to access these variables all I can do something like this:

```
import global_var

# read var
print global_var.x
# change var
global_var.x = 0
```

What I have noticed is that sometimes if I change a global variable and immediately try to read it then sometimes I get the old value. For example

```
import global_var

global_var.x = 'new'
if global_var.x == 'new':
    print 'changed'
else:
    print 'not changed'
```

The above operation appears to be probabilistic via asynchronicity. So what is up with this, is there a way to make this sort of thing deterministic, or should I just not do this?

---

Ok I found my bug, python still works and is as synchronous as ever, all is well, thanks for everyones time and suggestions.

Comment: It's safe to assume that the `=` operator works. Something else is going on, do you have a circular import somewhere maybe?

Comment: Uhm, what is "probabilistic via asynchronicity" supposed to mean? Whatever problem you have, it wont happen in the code above ...

Comment: "probabilistic via asynchronicity" Means sometimes it works, sometimes it don't and no other parameters change. So the behavior is probabilistic, and I am guessing it is because some part of this process is asynchronous.

Comment: I understand everything everyone is saying and generally agree, but I see what I see and I have already checked all the simple things everyone is pointing out. I will continue to assume this is unreliable until someone can actually tell me why it is reliable rather than asserting that it is.

Comment: It's reliable because that's the way it is implemented.  If you actually have an example that other people can use to reproduce the behavior you're describing (so, complete and preferably minimal - see http://sscce.org/) then perhaps you've found a bug that should be fixed.  However, given the extremely basic and fundamental nature of the feature in question - set an attribute on a module - it doesn't seem very likely that the bug is in the runtime, but instead is in your program.  If you can share that complete, minimal example then perhaps someone can point out exactly where it goes wrong.

Comment: I'd love to do this, I not sure I will because I already have a fix. But its weird, I could change the statistics of this just by printing the variable before I use it.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior you described isn't something that should ever happen if you're just doing the thing you said you're doing.  Double check your code, perhaps you don't actually set a new value in certain cases you think you do; or perhaps you read before you write sometimes; or maybe you have threads, and the exact ordering of reads and writes is non-deterministic.  If your globals are actually in your `__main__` module (that is, the .py file you execute on the command line), then maybe you have two copies of them (one copy created when the .py file is turned into the `__main__` module because you ran it on the command line; a second copy created when another module imports it by its name, creating a new module with a duplicate copy of all your code and data).  As a *very* unlikely alternative, perhaps the memory in your computer is failing and causing incorrect, unpredictable behavior.

Setting an attribute always sets it (or at least calls the special method which is responsible for setting it - you might override this special method to *not* set it for some reason, but then it's your fault. :)

Beyond that, using "global variable modules" like this is a bad idea if you want to create understandable, maintainable, testable(, working) software.  This is a kind of "spooky action at a distance".  Who knows what other parts of your program you will affect whenever you set one of these variables.  Instead of this pattern, pass arguments to each function.  Make each function's signature include all of the state that it needs to do its job.  If you have a lot of state and don't like long argument signatures, then consider making objects to hold that state and adding methods to those objects.